# How can I start a background process on a remote machine using perl and Net::OpenSSH?

Tags: perl, background-process, remote-access, cpan, openssh

I'm trying to use `Net::OpenSSH` to log into a remote machine, and start a background process.

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new( $username . "\@" . $host, key_path => $key, async => 1);

$ssh->error and die "Open ssh error: " . $ssh->error;

my $out = $ssh->system("nohup ./apache-jmeter-2.8/bin/jmeter-server > /dev/null &");

print $out;
```

When this runs, it logs into the machine, and I get the jmeter-server prompt
- if I enter ctrl-C, then the perl script continues and the jmeter-server process starts properly.

I've tried the `Net::OpenSSH->new()` call with and without the **async** param, and I've also tried using **nohup** on the command, without any difference.

How can I eliminate the need for the `ctrl-c` so the script can run unattended?

Comment: Do you want to keep the remote program running after the perl script finishes or only while it is running?

Comment: @salva: I want it to keep running as a background task after the script is done.

Comment: then, you have to use the `system` method and run the command with `nohup` redirecting all the stdio channels to /dev/null: `"nohup $program >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null &"`

Comment: That worked!  Write it up as an answer & I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Net::OpenSSH manual](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH), you want to give the async => 1 flag to the system() call.

async => 1 on the new() call is not doing what you thought it might do

Comment: Nice. I didn't read that far down once I'd found the async flag in system. :-)